# Creating a static const Vec<String>

Tags: rust

I am trying to initialize a `Vec<String>` with some settings that can be reused over my code.

I am using `const left: Vec<String> = vec![...` but this doesn't work:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> names-generator.rs:2:27
   |
2  | const left: Vec<String> = vec![
   |                           ^ expected slice, found array of 93 elements
   |
   = note: expected type `Box<[std::string::String]>`
   = note:    found type `Box<[&str; 93]>`
   = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate
```

What is the recommended way of doing something like this?

Comment: String literals are of type `&'static str`, not `String`. `String` is a string on heap.

Comment: They are not unrelated; in fact they are strongly related. The **only way** to make a `Vec` *or* a `String` is at runtime because they each require heap allocation. The only way to have a single instance of a runtime value like `Vec` or `String` is through the mechanism of somethign like `InitOnce` or `lazy_static!`.

Comment: the answer bellow works for me and I am not using any of those.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Do you want it to be mutable? Do the values have to be `String`s? If the answer is "no" to both, you can use an array of string slices (`[&str; N]`) instead of a `Vec<String>`:

```
const LEFT: [&'static str; 3] = ["Hello", "World", "!"];
// or
const LEFT: &'static [&'static str] = &["Hello", "World", "!"];
```

`const`s are basically copied wherever they are used, so the second form may be preferable depending on the size of the array.

Comment: The array is quite big. so probably I don't want it copied everywhere. Still trying to make sense of that signature though. Thanks

Comment: The first one is an array of 3 references to static strings, the second one is a reference to a static array of references to static strings. Static here means the lifetime = lifetime of the program, so effectively stuff that's stored in the DATA section of the executable. I see that the array has 93 elements: 93 64-bit pointers is way smaller than a CPU cache line so the first signature might actually be faster, definitely worth benchmarking.

Comment: @glebm Not true. A CPU cache line (on typical desktop and mobile CPUs) is 64 bytes. 93 64-bit pointers would occupy 744 bytes in total, or 12 cache lines.

Comment: @BrennanVincent is absolutely right. Also each slice is actually a pointer + length, so it's 16 bytes per slice.

Comment: And if the answer is "yes" to either... we do... what?

Comment: @Mike: If the answer is "yes" then initialization at runtime is required, possibly using [lazy_static](https://crates.io/crates/lazy_static) or similar tools to ensure that initialization is performed exactly once.